# SQL 2008 SUM by date with range specified

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sum

This is what I have so far. The problem is that I do not want these results in separate results windows. I want them in one result window as SUM grouped bay date but with the specific date range being used.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME, @DailyBeginDate DATETIME
--SET ME WEEKLY
SELECT @StartDate = '12/7/2015 7:00:00', @EndDate = '1/13/2016 7:00:00'
SET @DailyBeginDate = @StartDate
WHILE @DailyBeginDate < @EndDate
BEGIN
SELECT SUM(TotalCouponBet),@DailyBeginDate from Play (nolock)
WHERE GameServerInsertDT >= @DailyBeginDate
AND GameServerInsertDT < DATEADD(DD, 1, @DailyBeginDate)
SELECT @DailyBeginDate = DATEADD(DD, 1, @DailyBeginDate)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive date cte to get your dates, then outer apply the sum from the Play table.

```
;WITH dateCTE
AS
(
    SELECT  @StartDate StartDate,
            DATEADD(DD,1,@StartDate) EndDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD(DD,1,StartDate), 
            DATEADD(DD,1,EndDate)
    FROM    dateCTE
    WHERE   DATEADD(DD,1,StartDate) <= @EndDate
)

SELECT  cte.StartDate, 
        tcb.TotalCouponBet
FROM    dateCTE cte
OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(p.TotalCouponBet) TotalCouponBet 
             FROM   Play p (NOLOCK)
             WHERE  p.GameServerInsertDT >= cte.StartDate
                    AND p.GameServerInsertDT < DATEADD(DD,1,cte.EndDate)
            ) tcb
```

Another option is to left join the CTE to the Play table

```
;WITH dateCTE
AS
(
    SELECT  @StartDate StartDate,
            DATEADD(DD,1,@StartDate) EndDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD(DD,1,StartDate), 
            DATEADD(DD,1,EndDate)
    FROM    dateCTE
    WHERE   DATEADD(DD,1,StartDate) <= @EndDate
)

SELECT  cte.StartDate, 
        SUM(tcb.TotalCouponBet) TotalCouponBet
FROM    dateCTE cte
        LEFT JOIN Play p (NOLOCK)   ON p.GameServerInsertDT >= cte.StartDate
                                    AND p.GameServerInsertDT < DATEADD(DD,1,cte.EndDate)
GROUP BY cte.StartDate
```

if the @EndDate time doesn't have to match the @StartDate time, you can use this cte to get an accurate EndDate time for the last record..

```
;WITH dateCTE
AS
(
    SELECT  @StartDate StartDate,
            (CASE WHEN DATEADD(DD,1,@StartDate) > @EndDate THEN @EndDate ELSE DATEADD(DD,1,@StartDate) END) EndDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD(DD,1,StartDate), 
            CASE WHEN DATEADD(DD,1,EndDate) > @EndDate THEN @EndDate ELSE DATEADD(DD,1,EndDate) END
    FROM    dateCTE
    WHERE   DATEADD(DD,1,StartDate) <= @EndDate
)
```